# Passing extra variable to listener function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, listener

I have this piece of code

```
function main(b)
{
    b.on('func1', onFunc1);
    b.on('func2', onFunc2);
}

function onFunc1(a)
{
  console.log(a); //prints (for example) 2
  console.log(b); //is this possible?
}
```

So my question is, is there any way that I can pass to function 'onFunc1' variable named 'b'?

Comment: What is `b`? Is it a jQuery object? Does it contain only one element? If that's the case, then `this` will be bound to `b[0]` (the underlying DOM element) within `onFunc1()`.

Comment: is this as simple as `function onFunc1(a, b)` ?

Comment: @morels: That edit was uncalled for. `.on` is also an EventEmitter method. So, why should it be tagged `jquery` and not `nodejs`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
function main(b) {
    b.on('func1', function(){ onFunc1(b); });
    b.on('func2', function(){ onFunc2(b); });
}

function onFunc1(a) {
  console.log(a); //prints (for example) 2
  console.log(b); //is this possible?
}
```

Doing it this way, the anonymous function will get called, and will call your handler passing the function that you want it to pass.

Answer (score -1):

As it is written in the documentation you can insert an object containing data as the second field of the call:

```
function myHandler( event ) {
  alert( event.data.foo );
}
$( "p" ).on( "click", { foo: "bar" }, myHandler );
```

For further info pls see [jQuery on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: What makes you think the OP uses jQuery?

Comment: Because in this case @angarD has written code that uses `.on()`, that is a  jQuery function and what it does is compatible with his question. If it is not @angarD is free to say the contrary. If you have any better idea on that framework should be please tell me.

Comment: `.on` is a pretty common name for a method that binds event handlers. It's by no means special or specific to jQuery. E.g. [Node's `EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_event_listener) uses `.on` as well. `b` might be an instance of `EventEmitter`. Or maybe it's the OP's own implementation. `b` could just be `{on: function(event, handler) { /* do something */ }}`. Assuming this is jQuery is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling, reading the link you posted and looking around for similar questions I understood better.

Comment: Actually I was working with Node and EventEmitter. JQuery tag was accidental. I wasn't even aware that I put that tag also.
Sorry for late response.